# How to let GPT get knowledge from Notion?

Tags: schema, chatgpt-api, knowledge-management

How to use chat GPT "actions" to make a Notion page a **domain knowledge base?**

For now my code is that below (with page ID changed), it connects via API (bearer) but after a second GPT stops talking to it... any ideas how to fix it?

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
title: Notion Page Retrieval API
description: API for retrieving a specific page from Notion.
version: 1.0.0
servers:

- url: https://api.notion.com/
  description: Notion API server
  paths:
  /pages/{pageIdEx1234567890987654321}:
  get:
  operationId: retrieveNotionPage
  summary: Retrieves a specific Notion page
  description: Fetches details of the specified Notion page.
  responses:
  '200':
  description: Notion page details
  content:
  application/json:
  schema:
  type: object
  properties:
  object:
  type: string
  id:
  type: string
  created_time:
  type: string
  last_edited_time:
  type: string
  title:
  type: string
  content:
  type: string
```